# Using Boost.Log together with Boost.Asio services

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging, boost, boost-asio

I have a server which uses boost.asio services. I use boost.log for logging with an asynchronous sink. The asio_io_service gets started within an own thread. The logger gets initialized in the main thread before starting the server. The server accepts connections with async_accept and reads and sends messages also asynchronously.

Now I have the problem, that the logger logs only messages when the server is doing something, e.g. receiving messages. When I log a message after logger initialization and before starting the server I can see this log message only after the first message was received by the server. But I want to log messages even when no server actions happen. Have you an idea what the problem is and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, the related stackoverflow-questions gave me the answer :) It was the by default disabled auto_flush. So this single line in the logger initialization was the solution:

```
sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);
```

Comment: Actually if you are using Boost.log Asynchronous sinks, auto_flush(true) has no effects.